# DataFrame operation on all columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, logging

I have a DataFrame, with date index of 250 trading days in 2017 and column of 100 stock tickers.

The DataFrame is therefore a *250 x 100* matrix, containing the daily closing price series of each stock across all trading days last year.

What I would like to do to this whole DataFrame is to apply the `numpy.log` operation to calculate the log daily returns for each stock - i.e. apply this log operation to each and every column in this DataFrame.

While I've looked up previous posts on single column series of DataFrame to carry out this manoeuvre, I don't know what will be a neat way to do this operation across the whole DataFrame of all its columns -- thinking should I do something like:

```
log_matrix1 = np.log(df[1:,:]/df[:-1,:])
```

This doesn't work as I get unhashable type error.

Many thanks for helping!

Comment: Please add the full exception and an example of the dataframe.

Comment: Sounds like you want to groupby ticker and date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different approaches. I recommend you use NumPy arrays. Just note that `log(a / b) = log(a) - log(b)` is true for the natural logirthm. So you can first take the logarithms of each value and then take the difference.

Here's an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5))

print(df)

          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.698647  0.185940  0.656863  0.238429  0.746046
1  0.544250  0.240666  0.963219  0.398320  0.181753
2  0.503546  0.300948  0.751702  0.887889  0.982929
3  0.643171  0.239419  0.515604  0.922263  0.028100
4  0.163588  0.044437  0.023044  0.698208  0.238952
```

Then take the difference of the logs:

```
res1 = pd.DataFrame(np.diff(np.log(df.values), axis=0))
res2 = pd.DataFrame(np.log(df).diff()).iloc[1:]

assert (res1.values == res2.values).all()

print(res1)

          0         1         2         3         4
0 -0.249738  0.257984  0.382805  0.513184 -1.412139
1 -0.077732  0.223528 -0.247941  0.801592  1.687888
2  0.244735 -0.228720 -0.377000  0.037984 -3.554767
3 -1.369059 -1.684144 -3.107937 -0.278313  2.140491
```

Comment: Thank you for this demo. In res1, how do I know it's taking the log difference of the row(i+1) from row(i) and not the other way round pls?

Comment: You can look up the docs for [`numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html). You'll find the `axis` parameter specifies which differences you take. `axis=0` means row-wise. You can also calculate it manually to check.

Comment: @cqstack, If this answer helped, please feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (green tick on left).